# kafka-python KafkaConsumer multiple partition commit offset

Tags: python, apache-kafka, commit

Is it possible at all to commit offsets to Kafka topic which have multiple partitions so offset1 can be commited to partition1, offset2 to p2 and so on?

EDIT:

Yes, it is possible:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer()
topicpartitions = [TopicPartition('topicname', partitionId) for partitionId in consumer.partitions_for_topic('topicname')]

consumer.assign(topicpartitions)
for tp in topicpartitions:
    consumer.commit({tp: OffsetAndMetadata(1000, None)})

for msg in consumer:
    #do whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Kafka offsets are always per partition. What I mean is that if your topic has 2 partitions the the messages in p0 would start at offset 0 and increase my 1 for each new message. The messages in p1 similarity start at offset 0 and increase by 1.

So if you published two messages (without keys) one would go in partition 0 with offset 0 and the other would go into partition 1 with offset 0.

Now if another app were consuming this topic and were to commit its offsets then it will be producing messages into the `__consumer_offsets` topic that includes its group.id, topic, partition number, and offset. For example, something like {"myconsumerid","mytopic",P0,1} and {"myconsumerid","mytopic",P1,1}.

Should the app stop and one or two other consumer start with the same group.id they will continue from the last committed offset for which ever partition(s) they are assigned.

If you want to reposition a consumers offsets to any other position you can change the committed offsets for the group using the 0.11 Kafka tool

> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --reset-offsets

This tool will allow you to set the offset for each partition independantly if you give it the right flags.

You can call this tool from a Python program if you like. All existing consumers in the consumer group should be shutdown first or they may over write the offsets.

If you want to write a Python version of this tool rather than running the existing CLI command you need to find a Python client that supports seek() or so you can change the offsets to what you want them to be and then commit them in that position for when the consuming app restarts. An alternative would be to forgo dynamic partition assignment and manually assign() the partitions you want to change and commit offsets to the assigned list. You cannot use dynamically managed partition subscriptions and manually assigned partitions at the same time in the same app.

You will also need to ensure that all other consumers using the same consumer group on these partitions are shut down or the committed offsets will get overwritten by the other consumers as soon as they auto-commit or manually commit their offsets over the ones you have just set.

Comment: Your answer does not refer the question. The question is if it is possible to commit offsets to kafka topic partitions in python. So, imagine you have a topic few 12 partitions and you want to commit a dict of 12 k:v pairs to kafka where k=partition and v=offset value so next time you start consumption of the messages stored in that topic from the offsets you commited manualy earlier. e.g. topic has 10000 msgs distributed equally accross 10 partitions. you want to start from manualy forced offsets.

Comment: You cannot write messages and assign your own offset in any language. Offsets are generated by the broker and are always monotomicly increasing. Producing messages creates offsets automatically. Consuming and and calling commitSync() is what commits the consumers offsets. Are you asking if you can reposition a consumers existing committed offsets to be something else because that's possible with the admin tools.

Comment: Kafka stores messages in the topic. Each message has got an offset. KafkaConsumer can commit offset back to kafka. Kafka can store information about commited offsets as well. You can force KafkaConsumer to consume from either earliest or latest offset or from specific offset value. My question is: how to force KafkaConsumer to consume messages from kafka topic with multiple partitions from specific offsets set manualy for each of the partitions.

Comment: I'm trying to help you and your question is a bit ambiguous so don't get upset if I have interpreted it incorrectly. You should ask if it's possible to "reset" the committed offsets for a consumer group using Python. You don't say which of the 3 Kafka Python clients you are using. You don't say what version of Kafka you are using.

Comment: No, I do not want to reset the offset. You can simply reset the offset by changing the group_id. I do say which of the client -> just read the question: it says 'kafka-python' and this is the name of the client. kafka ver is >0.8.2

Comment: I know how to manually commit the offset for Kafka topic partition. I do not know how to manually commit offsets for Kafka topic with multiple partitions so I can set different offset value commited for each of the partitions.

Comment: When you commit offsets it commits them for all the partitions you are consuming. It doesn't matter in there is 1 partition or many. You only commit the current positions for all partitions.

Comment: Don't worry mate. I have just got the solution. I will put the answer in the EDIT section of the question.

Comment: That will be tremendously enlightening and might allow me to actually understand  what your original question was.